# Error when applying sympy.exp( ) to an ndarray

Tags: python, sympy

all. I was trying to obtain a matrix expression in terms of a vector of symbolic variables. But the result says y1's type is unknown. When I tried to assign y1 to a row of a matrix, an error popped up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbi89.png)

*The code is as below:*

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x:'+str(6), Real=True)
x11 = np.array(x)
X = x11.reshape(2,3) 

C = np.random.rand(2,3)
Y = np.zeros((2,3))
r_sq = np.sum((X-C)**2,axis=0)
eps = 0.98
V = -eps**2*r_sq
y1 = sp.exp(V)

Y[0,:] = y1
```

**Can anyone give some pointers? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: numpy and sympy aren't meant to be mixed.  (PS: Please add the error in text format to your post.)

Answer (score 1):

If you convert `V` to a sympy Matrix then you can apply the exp function to its elements:

```
In [6]: sp.Matrix(V).applyfunc(sp.exp)
Out[6]: 
⎡                                  2                                  2 ⎤
⎢ - 0.9604⋅(x₀ - 0.896250131953416)  - 0.9604⋅(x₃ - 0.881772704175947)  ⎥
⎢ℯ                                                                      ⎥
⎢                                                                       ⎥
⎢                                  2                                   2⎥
⎢ - 0.9604⋅(x₁ - 0.117448022545194)  - 0.9604⋅(x₄ - 0.0987476579989179) ⎥
⎢ℯ                                                                      ⎥
⎢                                                                       ⎥
⎢                                  2                                  2 ⎥
⎢ - 0.9604⋅(x₂ - 0.208646464519804)  - 0.9604⋅(x₅ - 0.317326771815641)  ⎥
⎣ℯ                                                                      ⎦
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are mixing Numpy and Sympy: this might produce unexpected results.

One such unexpected result was pointed out by Oscar: differently from `np.expr`, `sp.exp` doesn't get applied on a per-element base of an array.

```py
y1 = sp.Matrix(V).applyfunc(sp.exp)
```

Then, `Y` must be a SymPy matrix. Since you want to modify it in-place, it must be a `MutableDenseMatrix`:

```
Y = sp.MutableDenseMatrix(sp.zeros(2, 3))
Y[0, :] = y1.T
Y
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right is saying it's best to stick with `sympy`, or `numpy`, and not to mix them, but lets examine your code in some detail.

I find it useful to look at the `sympy` (and `numpy`) variables as we go along.  I also like to see them in questions (saves me some work):

```
In [1]: import sympy as sp
   ...: 
   ...: x = sp.symbols('x:'+str(6), Real=True)
   ...: x11 = np.array(x)
   ...: X = x11.reshape(2,3)
```

`X` is an object dtype array, containing symbols.  Math on such an array his hit-or-miss.  Operators tend to be ok, since sympy symbols and expr also implement most of the operators.  Functions like `exp` and `sqrt` fail.

```
In [2]: X
Out[2]: 
array([[x0, x1, x2],
       [x3, x4, x5]], dtype=object)

In [3]: type(X[0,1])
Out[3]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol

In [4]: C = np.random.rand(2,3)
```

So this math works:

```
In [5]: X-C
Out[5]: 
array([[x0 - 0.53151310056324, x1 - 0.230185787985989,
        x2 - 0.614339325415671],
       [x3 - 0.843273631776074, x4 - 0.688538213396761,
        x5 - 0.686219679978976]], dtype=object)

In [6]: (X-C)**2
Out[6]: 
array([[(x0 - 0.53151310056324)**2, (x1 - 0.230185787985989)**2,
        (x2 - 0.614339325415671)**2],
       [(x3 - 0.843273631776074)**2, (x4 - 0.688538213396761)**2,
        (x5 - 0.686219679978976)**2]], dtype=object)

In [7]: np.sum((X-C)**2, axis=0)
Out[7]: 
array([(x0 - 0.53151310056324)**2 + (x3 - 0.843273631776074)**2,
       (x1 - 0.230185787985989)**2 + (x4 - 0.688538213396761)**2,
       (x2 - 0.614339325415671)**2 + (x5 - 0.686219679978976)**2],
      dtype=object)

In [8]: r_sq = _

In [9]: eps = 0.98
   ...: V = -eps**2*r_sq

In [10]: V
Out[10]: 
array([-0.9604*(x0 - 0.53151310056324)**2 - 0.9604*(x3 - 0.843273631776074)**2,
       -0.9604*(x1 - 0.230185787985989)**2 - 0.9604*(x4 - 0.688538213396761)**2,
       -0.9604*(x2 - 0.614339325415671)**2 - 0.9604*(x5 - 0.686219679978976)**2],
      dtype=object)
```

With the sum, `V` is a (3,) array - still object.

The sympy `exp` does evaluate any of those terms.

```
In [13]: y1 = sp.exp(V)

In [14]: y1
Out[14]: 
 ⎡                                2                                  2        
 ⎣- 0.9604⋅(x₀ - 0.53151310056324)  - 0.9604⋅(x₃ - 0.843273631776074)   - 0.96
ℯ                                                                             

                           2                                  2               
04⋅(x₁ - 0.230185787985989)  - 0.9604⋅(x₄ - 0.688538213396761)   - 0.9604⋅(x₂ 
                                                                              

                    2                                  2⎤
- 0.614339325415671)  - 0.9604⋅(x₅ - 0.686219679978976) ⎦
```

`y1` is one `sympy.exp`. There's no way it can be assigned to a `float` dtype array like `Y`.

```
In [19]: Y
Out[19]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

`Y[0,0]` assignment must be float or something that can be evaluated to such.  Your `y1` does not qualify.

```
float(y1) # AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute '_eval_evalf'
```

The others suggest make a sympy matrix:

```
In [34]: y2 = sp.Matrix(V).applyfunc(sp.exp)

In [35]: type(y2)
Out[35]: sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix

In [36]: y2.shape
Out[36]: (3, 1)
```

We could make a numpy array, object dtype, from that, but to what purpose?

### sympy matrix

```
In [51]: M = Matrix(x).reshape(2,3)

In [52]: M
Out[52]: 
⎡x₀  x₁  x₂⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣x₃  x₄  x₅⎦

In [53]: M1= M-C

In [54]: M2= M1.multiply_elementwise(M1)  # M1**2 doesn't work

In [55]: M2
Out[55]: 
⎡                       2                           2                         
⎢(x₀ - 0.53151310056324)    (x₁ - 0.230185787985989)   (x₂ - 0.614339325415671
⎢                                                                             
⎢                        2                          2                         
⎣(x₃ - 0.843273631776074)   (x₄ - 0.688538213396761)   (x₅ - 0.686219679978976

 2⎤
) ⎥
  ⎥
 2⎥
) ⎦
```

I haven't worked much with `sympy.Matrix`, but it looks like its operators, like `*` and `**` (and `sp.exp`) favor the matrix versions, not the elementwise ones.  So continuing along this route will require more study of the `Matrix` docs.

```
In [61]: r_sq = M2[0,:]+M2[1,:]

In [62]: V = -eps**2*r_sq

In [63]: V.shape
Out[63]: (1, 3)

In [64]: V
Out[64]: 
⎡                                2                                  2         
⎣- 0.9604⋅(x₀ - 0.53151310056324)  - 0.9604⋅(x₃ - 0.843273631776074)   - 0.960

                          2                                  2                
4⋅(x₁ - 0.230185787985989)  - 0.9604⋅(x₄ - 0.688538213396761)   - 0.9604⋅(x₂ -

                   2                                  2⎤
 0.614339325415671)  - 0.9604⋅(x₅ - 0.686219679978976) ⎦

In [65]: y3 = V.applyfunc(sp.exp)

In [67]: y3
Out[67]: 
⎡                                 2                                  2        
⎢ - 0.9604⋅(x₀ - 0.53151310056324)  - 0.9604⋅(x₃ - 0.843273631776074)    - 0.9
⎣ℯ                                                                      ℯ     

                            2                                  2              
604⋅(x₁ - 0.230185787985989)  - 0.9604⋅(x₄ - 0.688538213396761)    - 0.9604⋅(x
                                                                  ℯ           

                      2                                  2⎤
₂ - 0.614339325415671)  - 0.9604⋅(x₅ - 0.686219679978976) ⎥
                                                          ⎦
```

This `y3` is (1,3), while `y2` is (3,1), but the terms are the same.

### List comprehension on `V`

Another way to apply the `sp.exp` to `V` is to use a list comprehension:

```
y4 = [sp.exp(expr) for expr in V[0,:]]
```

For object dtype arrays, there's no disadvantage to using list comprehensions.  Another way is:

```
y5 = np.frompyfunc(sp.exp,1,1)(V)
```